# Gmail Forwarding api says forbidden

Tags: gmail-api

I was going through the api doc for setting forwarding address via gmail Apis
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.forwardingAddresses/create

I am getting the following error when trying to access this api.

```
    {
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

If there is a way to access this api? Few other doubts I have:

1. Can this be used for any personal @gmail.com accounts?
2. Can this be also used for any gsuite domains like @example.com?

Comment: could you add your authorization code so i can have a look?

Comment: Are you using a service account with delegated domain-wide authority? Could you also provide a little context on what you are trying to do?

Comment: As i can see from the doc which states "As a G Suite administrator, you can use domain-wide delegation of authority to grant third-party and internal applications access to your G Suite users' data."
Does that mean even after using oAuth flow I wont be able to set forwarding via api in any account even after a user has given permissions to the api for the required scope?
Link to doc - https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not possible

*At least for accounts outside a domain that you administrate*

If I understand correctly, you wish to make an app that will ask for a users permission to allow your app to set up email forwarding for them via the API.

The listing in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) for the scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing` which is required for that endpoint says:

> Operations guarded by this scope are restricted to administrative use only. They are only available to Google Workspace customers using a service account with domain-wide delegation.

This is as much as security measure as anything. Which means that what you are trying to do is not possible, unless it was for members of your domain only.

It will not work for gmail accounts or other domains. You need to authorise it properly.

If you wanted to get it working for your domain, your first step needs to be getting a service account working, [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) is a good starting point.

References

- [OAuth Scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)
- [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)